# Was bedeutet eigentlich "laufen"?

Tags: meaning, verb

Laut [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=laufen) kann das Wort "laufen" sowohl mit "to walk" als auch mit "to run" übersetzt werden. Wann wird "laufen" verwendet und wie weiß ich, was gemeint ist?

> "Er läuft die Straße entlang." -  Is he running or walking?

Comment: A google image search for "laufen" is all about "running".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der Kontext ist wichtig. Zum Beispiel kann "laufen" auch für "joggen" verwendet werden. Es ist ein allgemeineres Wort für Fortbewegung (aber nicht universal einsetzbar), als das spezifischere "rennen".

> Er läuft die Straße entlang.

Ohne weiteren Kontext ist hier "walking" gemeint. Es könnte auch "jogging" gemeint sein, aber nicht "rennen". "Rennen" könnte er hier nur, wenn es schon vorher erwähnt worden wäre und man eine Wiederholung des Verbs vermeiden möchte.

Es gibt Situationen, wo "laufen" nur als "rennen" interpretiert werden kann, zum Beispiel als Warnung/Befehl:

> Lauf! Lauf so schnell Du kannst!
>
> Run, run as fast as you can!

"walk" oder "jog" ergeben bei einer solchen Aufforderung keinen Sinn.

> Ich geh laufen.

Diesen Satz hört man von Leuten, die regelmäßig joggen und jetzt im Moment diesem Sport nachgehen möchten. Sie ziehen ihre Sportsachen an und fangen an zu laufen/joggen.

Der Kontext ist entscheidend. Wenn dieser fehlt, würde ich vom "walk"-Äquivalent ausgehen.

**Ergänzung:** (nur um die Verwirrung zu vergrößern ;)

Das Substantiv "[der Lauf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lauf)" wird (unter anderem) verwendet um [Rennen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rennen) (races, sprints) zu beschreiben:

> Der Marathonlauf (marathon)
> Der Hundertmeterlauf (hundred meters, 100-meter sprints)
> Der Hürdenlauf (hurdle race, hurdles)

Hier passt nur der Kontext von "run" und "jog", nicht der von "walk".

Comment: Very good answer. One might add that people in the South of Germany do usually translate “laufen” as “walking” (when it means a movement). They'd use “rennen”, “springen” or “joggen” for faster movements.

Comment: I'm from South Tyrol where *laufen* always means *running* (rennen)

Answer (score 2):

- Die Geschäfte laufen
- Der Fernseher läuft
- Die Nase läuft
- Es läuft

A running nose and a running TV are common in the US too, aren't they? But running business?

> Er läuft die Straße entlang.

Ohne weiteren Kontext ist hier "running" gemeint. Nein, im Ernst: Man geht die Straße entlang, oder man läuft, man rennt, man eilt, man flaniert, man flitzt, man kriecht, man schlendert.

Das Wort ist zweideutig, und wenn der Schreiber die Zweideutigkeit nicht bedacht hat, dann hat er zuvor den aufklärenden Kontext vielleicht nicht geliefert, meint aber doch bestimmt das eine oder das andere.